# Adding a vertical line to a geom_freqpoly plot according to the data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to add a vertical to a `geom_freqpoly` where the x-axis location of the line is to be determined according to the trend of the curve. Specifically I'm looking for the x-axis location where the curve flattens out - the last inflection point.

To illustrate:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=diamonds, aes(carat))+geom_freqpoly(binwidth = 0.1)
```

gives this plot:
[image]

I want to add a vertical line at x =~ 2.5 [image]to get:

So my question is how do I find this last inflection point which determines the x-axis location?

Comment: Wouldn't the inflection point be at 2?  Your interpretation could also argue that 4 is also an inflection point as it is the last highest number.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question.  If I am thinking about this correctly you are looking for the last point with a certain tolerance -- say 26.  This might be a bit of a hack, but it will work and you can modify it for your data.

**ggplot setup**

```
library(ggplot2)
b <- ggplot(data=diamonds, aes(carat)) + geom_freqpoly(binwidth = 0.1)
```

**Inflection point function**

The point of this function is to return the "inflection point" from the ggplot model defined above, with a given tolerance from previous data point -- say >= 26 -- and desired last number from the inflection point vector.

```
get_infl <- function(ggplot_model, tolerance, last){
  bg <- ggplot_build(ggplot_model)
  dat <- bg$data[[1]]
  y <- dat$y
  x <- dat$x
  loc <- tail(which(diff(y)>=tolerance),10)+1L
  newloc <- loc[[length(loc) - last + 1]]
  return(x[[newloc]])
}
```

**New ggplot with V-line**: tolerance 26 and last

```
ggplot(data=diamonds, aes(carat)) + 
  geom_freqpoly(binwidth = 0.1) + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = get_infl(b, 26, 1), color = "red")
```

[image]

**New ggplot with V-line**: tolerance 26 and second from last

```
ggplot(data=diamonds, aes(carat)) + 
  geom_freqpoly(binwidth = 0.1) + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = get_infl(b, 26, 2), color = "red")
```

[image]